# Difference between Crawling and getiting links with Html Agility pack,

Tags: parsing, web-crawler, console-application, html-agility-pack, domcrawler

i am getting links of a website using Html Agility pack with console application c#, by giving the divs that i want and get the links from those divs, my question is the thing i am doing is crawling or parsing, if not then what is crawling

Comment: I would not call it crawling, unless it is recursive. If you are extracting all links from a given url - by all I mean links referenced by the links and so on. If you are simply trying to extract the href values of links that show up in a given url, this is parsing only.

Comment: thanks mate,no i am extracting all links e.g images pages prices descriptions and other links too from a e-commerce site, it is crawling then right?

Comment: I would call this crawling, yes.